# expo run:android fails with cryptic message

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a managed expo project with expo-dev-client. I got the following error when running `expo run:android`. Could anyone points me to the right direction? I don't know which part of error is causing the development build to fail...

```
> Configure project :expo-application
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-av
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '/Users/hayatasuenaga/Job/personal-projects/eisuke-mobile-app/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 272

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-av'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/hayatasuenaga/Job/personal-projects/eisuke-mobile-app/android/local.properties'.
      > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```